# Как сделать эффекты на цифры?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать эффекты на цифры? Как сделать такой эффекты вертикально через javascript или jQuery без `margin`? [Типа такой цифры](http://vk.com/vk2016)

```
<div id="number">123456789</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
stripe.onclick = function() {
  stripe.classList.add('animate');
};
```

```css
#digit {
  width: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 32px "Courier New", monospace;
}

#stripe.animate {
  margin-left: -174px;
  transition-property: margin-left;
  transition-duration: 9s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="digit"><span id="stripe">0123456789</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая интересная js библиотека, [Odometer](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/), позволяет делать анимированные счетчики. Довольно удобная, легкая в использовании, есть возможность кастомизации.

[image: во время анимации]
[image: остановился]